# Asus G75VX - Replace DVD/Blu-Ray Player with a Wireless Card Module?

Tags: wireless-networking, asus-laptop

Since the wireless card is not so good, I'd like to solve this (before buying the laptop). Could you tell me if it is possible to replace the DVD player with a wireless card module?

I read somewhere that it is possible to replace the DVD player with a HDD, so I thought it would be cool to do the same with a new (additional) wireless module and solve this weak wireless performance.

Comment: @Ramhound: how exactly are you going to connect a wireless card to a sata interface?

Comment: This isn't possible.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - You are of course correct.  I am not sure what made me think they made optical disk players which work in the express card module slot.

Comment: @Ramhound: You were probably thinking about wireless headsets. Just to remark that power-wise the connection [looks feasible](http://www.amazon.com/15-Pin-6-Pin-Express-Power-Belstaf/dp/B00DOR7RHU).

Comment: @harrymc - The Lenovo laptop I have has a dvd drive that can be removed and replaced by various devices of the same interface.  It wouldn't be a far stretch to think a wireless card could be used, but after looking at the datasheet on the interface itself, its also clear it wasn't possible.

Comment: A Sata-PCIe power connector was the only one I could find. A data connector isn't feasible, because even if someone worked out such a connector the speed difference is too large.

Answer (score 8):

Nope, HDDs and DVDs use SATA. Wireless cards use mini-PCI-E usually, they are definitely not interchangeable. You're better off either replacing it with another mini-PCI-E card, [express card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExpressCard), or USB-based modules.

Answer (score 4):

This is just silly and completely impossible. Most hard drives and DVD drives these days use a SATA interface like so:

[image]

Typical wireless cards come in PCI Express:

[image]

Mini PCI Express:

[image]

Express Card:

[image]

Or USB:

[image]

There's no way you're plugging any of those directly into a SATA interface.

**A NOTE TO EVERYONE**: Don't ever, **EVER** try to plug one interface into another. This is bad. This on a huge list of things you shouldn't do and is up there with [cutting a graphics card to fit it in another slot.](http://lifehacker.com/5951156/convert-a-pci+e-x16-video-card-to-fit-a-x1-slot-with-a-diamond-cutting-wheel)

Comment: While your answer is 100% correct, the images would only confuse the laymen because the SATA plugs really look like they could fit in some of those PCI's.. :)

Comment: amusingly, I recall there's a safer way to convert graphics cards - by modifying risers.

Comment: That guy got the graphics card to work.  Probably not a good article to discourage hardware modification.